# Raspberry deleted folder reappears

Tags: linux, raspbian

I have recently bought a Raspberry Pi and made a setup with the standard Raspbian image. A few days ago I have made a folder on my desktop, I want to delete this folder but after reboot it continues to reappear.
There are NO applications running which recreates the folder on startup.
Somewhere on the interweb I read that using the 'sync' command it should be fixed, this however was not the issue.

I have no clue what is going on and I hope someone could offer me a valuable solution.

Comment: What's the name of the folder?

Comment: This is the specific folder: 
/home/pi/Desktop/sshkey

Comment: Is you SD still fine?

Comment: The issue was indeed, as McSinyx mentioned, my SD-CARD. Bought a new one and the problem is gone.